Issue with Persisting OneToMany relation on paremt entity using JPA JOINED inheritance type
I am having issues while persisting a child entity when parent entity  has OneToManay relationship with another entity. Could someone help what could be the issue with the following setup.
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name=PERSON)
Public class Person{  //parent class

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name='DB_ID)
private Long id;


@Column(name="PERSON_ID)
Private String personId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="person", cascade={cascadeType.PERSIST,cascadeType.MERGE}){
private List<Address> addresses;

}
} 


This is my child class
@Entity
@Table(name=EMPLOYEE)
Public class Employee extends Person{  
@Id
@Column(name="NAME)
Private String name;


}


This is the 3rd class for @OneToMany from Person to Adress
@Entity
@Table(name=ADRESS)
Public class Adress{ 

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name='DB_ID)
private Long id;


@Column(name="address)
Private String adress;

@ManytoOne
@joinColumn(name="parent_id", referenceColumnName="PERSON_ID")
private Person person;

}


Repository for saving child class
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Emploee, Long>{}

I am getting the below error.
cannot insert NULL into ("ADDRESS"."PARENT_ID")
Why would JPA throws this error even though i am setting "abc123" as person_id on Employee object before saving.
I am saving the entity using EmployeeRepository class but getting the following error. The  child entity has requored values
Employee employee = Employee.builder()
                      .name("john does")
                      .personId("abc123")
                      .address(addressist).build();

employeeRepository.save(employee);

I am expecting that records will be persisted in all 3 tables PERSON, EMPLOYEE and ADDRESS table but getting the error.

?Are you sure you have provided the correct entities? For instance, you can't use @Id in the name field of Employee. Can you update your entities with the exact fields and annotations?

I am using the shared id as foreign key between Employee and Person tables.I am not generating new id for Employee record. In this case it is totally fine

What exactly you have in addressist?
